# SQL Server 2012 Management Studio change color of comments?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

Odd question, but I can't seem to find a reliable answer on google. Is it possible for me to change the color of comments in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio? I am colorblind and need to better be able to identify them.

Comment: check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173754.aspx

Comment: Yes.  It's under Tools..Options.. [Fonts and Colors].  I do it all the time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Click **Options** on the **Tools** menu. Click **Environment**, and then click **Fonts and Colors**.

In the right pane, make sure **Text Editor** is selected, and then from the **Display Items** below, select the **Comment** list item, and change the **Item Foreground** color to a color you can see, and save it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tools => Options => Fonts and Colors
[image]